# Redirect to previous angular state after login

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a scenario where login and logout API's from third party service provider. Redirection to the above API's call happens in my web layer(using Spring) based on the available cookies and using Angularjs as front end.

Coming to my question, How can I redirect to previous Angular state after log-on into my application once user hits logout.

Comment: please post your code, what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about this two ways that I can think of.  If the data is simple enough, you can add it to the url as a query parameter.  If it is more involved, then you may want to look into using local storage.  You can save the state to local storage, and then retrieve it when you get redirected back into the app.  There are some edge cases you will have to consider, but that should work for you.